# Why does Windows Update install new languages?

Tags: windows-update

I just wanted to update my Windows (because I like my software to be up-to-date), and now Windows Update is downloading tons of language packs that I never asked for.

Why is Windows Update doing that?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when one selects all packages that are proposed in the "Optional updates" section of Windows Update:

[image: Windows update: Optional updates]

Do not install these optional updates. Or at least, not all of them blindly.

While proper package management systems like Ubuntu's would only show you updates for installed software, Windows Update also shows unrelated software that you most probably don't need, for instance all languages packs.

Installing all language packs [can result in disk and performance headaches](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2011/03/02/do-you-really-need-all-of-those-language-packs.aspx), so better not do it unless necessary.